# Mapping text and html. Position search

Tags: javascript, discrete-mathematics

I have text and this text with html

> Once upon a time there was a very rich man who lived with his three daughters. The two older daughters laughed at anyone who did not dress as wel as they did. If the two of them were not resting at home, they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could carry home.

```
<span>
    <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
        <p class="p1" style="margin: 0px; font: 17px; font-family: Helvetica Neue"><b>Once upon a time there was
                a
                very rich man who <span style="color: blue">lived</span> with his three daughters.<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;
                </span>The two older daughters laughed at anyone who di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot dress <span style="color: green">as</span> wel as they did.<span
                    class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp; </span>If the two of them were not resting at home,
                they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could <span style="color: red">carry</span> home. <span
                    class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></b></p><br>
    </div>
    <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    </div>
</span>
```

Need a universal solution to find the position of a word / phrase from text to html. The problem is that there may be some style in the word / phrase

```
di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot
```

Tried listening for shifts using Levenshtein distance but this is a very "hard" solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
let html = document.getElementById('input').innerHTML;
let word = 'did not';

console.log(searchPositions(html, word));

function searchPositions(html, issueText) {
    let htmlArr = Array.from(html).map((item, index) => {
        return {
            item,
            index
        }
    });

    const regexp = /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g;
    const tags = html.match(regexp) || [];
    const textTrue = html.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');

    let inTextStartPosition = textTrue.indexOf(issueText);
    let inTextEndPosition = inTextStartPosition + issueText.length - 1;

    let matches = [...html.matchAll(regexp)];
    let tagsIndexs = matches.map((item) => {
        return item.index;
    });

    let tagsInfo = tags.map((item, index) => {
        let length = item.length;
        let startPosition = tagsIndexs[index];
        let endPosition = startPosition + length;

        return {
            startPosition,
            endPosition,
            length
        }
    })

    for (let ii = 0; ii < tagsInfo.length; ii++) {
        let startPosition = tagsInfo[ii].startPosition;
        let endPosition = tagsInfo[ii].endPosition;

        while (startPosition !== endPosition) {
            htmlArr = htmlArr.filter(x => x.index !== startPosition);
            startPosition++;
        }
    }

    let start = htmlArr[inTextStartPosition].index;
    let end = htmlArr[inTextEndPosition].index;

    return {
        start,
        end
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='input'>
        <span>
            <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
                <p class="p1" style="margin: 0px; font: 17px; font-family: Helvetica Neue"><b>Once upon a time there was
                        a
                        very rich man who <span style="color: blue">lived</span> with his three daughters.<span
                            class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;
                        </span>The two older daughters laughed at anyone who di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot
                        dress <span style="color: green">as</span> wel as they did.<span
                            class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp; </span>If the two of them were not resting at home,
                        they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could <span
                            style="color: red">carry</span> home. <span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></b>
                </p><br>
            </div>
            <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```